# Tesseract - What should I do with multi font type?

Tags: windows, image, ocr, tesseract

I've a file input like this (only numbers but multi font types). So If I want to use Tesseract for trainning data. I should make a set of one font type in one tiff file or multi font type in one tiff file?

[image]

What is better, please show me some tips. Thanks all your helps.

Answer (score 1):

One font style in each training image. [Tesseract Training Wiki](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract3) states the following:

- The training data should be grouped by font. Ideally, all samples of
  a single font should go in a single tiff file, but this may be
  multi-page tiff (if you have libtiff or leptonica installed), so the
  total training data in a single font may be many pages and many 10s
  of thousands of characters, allowing training for large-character-set
  languages.
- DO NOT MIX FONTS IN AN IMAGE FILE (In a single .tr file to be
  precise.) This will cause features to be dropped at clustering, which
  leads to recognition errors.